# puzzles on using mutiple "addOptional" in function definitions

Tags: matlab

How to use multiple `addOptional` in function definitions?
`addOptional` is to add positional arguments. So I want to use it
in the following way.

- First I define the function and use two 
  `addOptional` there.
- Then I thought I can call in the following 
  two ways:
  `myfunc('Jim', 12)`   and `myfunc('Jim', 12, 'cm')`.
  However, the latter one throws an error:

  > *The argument 'cm' is a string and does not match any parameter names. It failed validation for the argument 'units'.*

But I can use as `myfunc('Jim', 12, 'units', 'cm')`, which seems the second `addOptional` behaves as `addParameter`, no longer like positional arguments. What's the mistake I made? Did I misunderstand something about `addOptional`? Many thanks!

Here is the definition of `myfunc()`:

```
  function myfunc(name, varargin)

  par = inputParser;

  defaultHeight = 1;
  defaultUnits = 'inches';

  addRequired(par, 'name', @ischar);
  addOptional(par, 'height', defaultHeight, @isnumeric);
  addOptional(par, 'units', defaultUnits);

  parse(par, name, varargin{:});

  disp(par.Results)
```

---

I found that if the positional arguments are NOT literal string (maybe called as *character vector* in helpdoc, the type shown by `whos` is `char`, e.g. `'any words'`), there would be no problems. For example, use `myfunc('Jim', 3, 4)` which is defined as

```
function myfunc(name, varargin)

p = inputParser;

addRequired(p, 'name');
addOptional(p, 'i', 1);
addOptional(p, 'j', 2);

parse(p, name, varargin{:});

disp(p.Results)
```

The [MATLAB help doc](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addoptional.html) doesn't mention anything about the limitations in data types of additional positional arguments. Does it imply this is a bug?

**Info**:

- MATLAB: 2016a
- OS: OS X Sierra